# Python : Finding combinations in column and doing relative operations using index values

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I need to find possible combinations (two pairs) in a list/column and perform a relative operation on relative column/list. Like, subtraction on values of the pairs.

Example input:

```
column 1 column2
----------------
A         10
C         20
B         30
```

Output

```
column1  column2    #internal operation
--------------------------------------
[A,B]    -20        A-B
[A,C]    -10        A-C
[C,B]    -10        C-B
```

I have used `itertools.combinations` for combinations.

Any tips to be get this done?

Comment: Yes. I have read the values from the file. I got the possible combinations also.

Comment: So what is the question exactly? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have posted the demo example. If, I have two columns. One with [A,B,C] and other with their values say [10,20,30]. I need to get the values of subtraction(pair(A,B)). i.e, for combination [A,B], i need the value output=10-30=-10 . With itertools.combinations, I get all combinations. But, not this operation or the index positions on the combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your initial columns into map P (`P = {'A': 10, ..}` etc.) and than just calculate `w = [((c1, c2), P[c1] - P[c2]) for c1, c2 in itertools.combinations(P.keys(), 2)]` . It should contain all data that you would like to put in resulting column.

To obtain data by columns: `letters_pairs, values = zip(*w)`

Comment: works like charm! Need to split the values into separate lists though.

Comment: Just use `zip`. Let `w = [((c1, c2), P[c1] - P[c2]) for c1, c2 in itertools.combinations(P.keys(), 2)]` than to split into columns: `zip(*w)`

Comment: Yea. I used it. Thanks anyway for posting it, @kkonard!

Comment: @kkonard I have a situation. My column2 data is in the form of u'10 km'. So, I need to convert unicode and replace ' km' to ''.

Comment: function to apply on column2 elements: `lambda x: int(x.split(' ')[0])`

Comment: @kkonard I used `dict(zip(col1,col2))`. But, the order is changed. Is it possible to create map/dict with same order as col1 elements?

Comment: @kkonard Should have used `OrderedDict`. My bad! Should have thought a little bit before asking!